# Lightbox 2 keeps getting bigger

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox2

I've implemented [Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) in my website, but I noticed a bug. The lightbox keeps getting bigger as I change pictures. After a while it looks like this:

[image]

I'm unfortunately not knowledgeable enough of JS, so I can't fix the code myself.

Comment: We probably won't be able to help much unless you post some code that's relevant to your problem.

Comment: Can you provide me the link for JS fiddle?

Comment: @Bobkhin I thought since I'm just using the plugin as is, that no code would be necessary. But I'll make a fiddle.

Comment: @Bobkhin Looks like I fixed it myself. Turns out there was some of my own css interfering with lightbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was some of my own css interfering with lightbox.

This element caused the issue:

```
img
{
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```